# Flutter watch changes on Google Drive File

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-drive-api

I'm currently using the google drive API in my flutter project and now I need to watch for changes of a specific file.
I tried the [files.watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/watch?hl=de) but got an error.
I imported the API as `import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as drive;`
and tried following code, while "id" is the id of my file I want to watch.

```
drive.Channel channel = drive.Channel();
var responseChannel = await driveApi.files.watch(channel, id!);
debugPrint(responseChannel.toString());
```

But all i get is a "DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: Unknown channel type: )"
Does anyone know how to properly use the watch function?

Comment: Can you share your request body for this method? The error is related to the channel type from your request. `files.watch` method request body must contain an instance of [channel](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/channels#Channel)

Comment: @George I don't really have a request body. My channel instance is just the channel object you see in the first line of the code