# Flutter watch changes on Google Drive File: which address?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-drive-api

I'm developing a simple app with flutter and I want to get informed when a specific file changes in my Google Drive account. Till now I can get the `fileId` of my file (and I can download the file .... but I needn't).

My current problem is, that I don't know what to set for the `address` field in `Channel()`. I know that it must be an https-address and not `'https//localhost'`. But which else? If I set my IP-address, then the call to `files.watch()` is running, but I don't get the expected notifications.

My questions are:

- what should I set in 'address'?
- how do I wait for the notifications?

```
String fileId ='my file id from Google Drive';
Channel channel =  Channel(id: const Uuid().v4(),
                       address: 'https://....', //<<<<< TODO ????
                       kind: "api#channel",
                       type: 'webhook'); // or 'web_hook'

var responseChannel  = await driveApi.files.watch(channel , fileId);
```

I've tried to set `address` to

- `https://localhost` : didn't work, because it is not allowed
- and to my public IP `https://77.66....` : the request is accepted by Google Drive Api, but I'm not receiving any notification when I change the watched file on Google Drive. And this is my second problem: I don't know how to wait for notifications.

Maybe I'm completly wrong with my attempt to get the notification within an flutter app. Then I need some hints what to look for.

There's a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77790192/23280924), but without solution till now.

Help would be very welcome.